# JavaScript stripping the .00 from my decimal?

Tags: javascript

Was wondering is anyone can shed some light onto why my subtotal is 1, and the .00 is being stripped off the subtotal.

price is 1.00, and itemQty is 1.

```
var price = parseFloat(res.productPrice).toFixed(2);
var subTotal = price * parseInt(res.itemQty);
```

Comment: You need to call `toFixed` on the subtotal as well.

Comment: Also worth noting this is just plain JavaScript not jQuery :)

Comment: @pankar in JavaScript there is no down casting since ints and floats are both `Number` objects. The thing is that even with floats all trailing zeros are removed. Because of this limitation `toFixed` returns a `String`, not a `Number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var price = parseFloat(res.productPrice).toFixed(2);
var subTotal = (price * parseInt(res.itemQty)).toFixed(2);
```

You have to call `toFixed()` on the subTotal to return a string rather than the number.

Answer (score 1):

`1` and `1.00` are the same thing, numerically.

`toFixed()` yields a string. A string is pretty much the only sense in which `1.00` and `1` are two different values.

In `price * parseInt(res.itemQty)` you're using your `"1.00"` string in a numerical operation, and so the value will be interpreted like a number. `subTotal` will be a number, as it is the result of a numerical operation, and thus it is both `1` and `1.00` at the same time.

If you want to present it with the decimals, you will need to convert it to a string using `toFixed` again.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to convert subTotal `toFixed()` again, as it's a number.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't made the subTotal a String using toFixed(2)

```
var res = {productPrice:3.00, itemQty:2}
var price = parseFloat(res.productPrice).toFixed(2);
var subTotal = price * parseInt(res.itemQty);

console.log(subTotal.toFixed(2));
```

I hope that helps